# Yii2 , How to save the logged in user's username in another table automatically?

Tags: yii2

In yii2 , what i am doing is user insert some data in one table . Now that particular table has a field called inserted_by . Now in inserted_by field i need the username of the user who inserted the data in that table . Username of the user is in table emp_info .

But the problem is username should be automatically inserted in the inserted_by field as that particular user is already logged in in the system . So in that inserted_by field i need to insert the username of the user who is logged in currenlty . How can i do it ?

Comment: Use `\Yii::$app->user->identity->username;` may be `\Yii::$app->user->username`

Comment: where should i use this code ? i mean like $model->requested_by=\Yii::$app->user->identity->username; ???

Comment: In controller `$model->inserted_by=\Yii::$app->user->identity->username;`

Comment: yeah its working !! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller add,

```
$model->inserted_by = \Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
```